# Regaining control of a group after being removed by another admin

Tags: facebook-groups

I created a Facebook group and was later removed by another admin.

How do I get my group back?

Comment: To be added back as  admin to your old group,you need to be first added as member of the group which you can send request to your friends to add it back and then you can ask the group admin to be give the right as admin

Answer (score 1):

This is too common on Facebook, one person cheating other of pages, groups and "famrville"! And the worst part is Facebook can't do anything in this, as giving admin privileges to other was your decision, no matter what happens next.

If you have a good fan falling in the group, ask some of your fans to request the current admin to add you back, this might force (wicked)admin to make you an admin again.

Or directly ask the other admins (if there are any) to add you.

If nothing helps, start a new group. What's the big problem?